# Combine two JS functions

Tags: javascript, function

Im currently trying to combine two if functions but somehow I only get errors. I already tried multiple ways of combining them with no result.

What I wanna do: I need to check if body has a specific class, if yes, a checkbox needs to be be unchecked.

What I tried to combine:

```
if (document.body.classList.contains('thatClass')) {
    // do some stuff
}

$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".main-nav-slideout") === false) {
      $("#main-nav-toggle").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

My try on combining the snippets:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if (document.body.classList.contains('thatClass')) && ($(e.target).is(".main-nav-slideout") === false) {
      $("#main-nav-toggle").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not a valid `if` statement. See the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Comment: Check your parentheses on that if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten it and just call the function when you need.

```js
$(function() {
  checkCheckbox()
  $(document).on("click", '.main-nav-slideout', checkCheckbox)
});

function checkCheckbox() {
  $("#main-nav-toggle").prop("checked", $('body').hasClass('thatClass'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class='thatClass'>
<input type='checkbox' id='main-nav-toggle' />
<div class='main-nav-slideout'>Click me</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if (document.body.getAttribute('class').split(' ').indexOf('thatClass')>-1 && ($(e.target).is(".main-nav-slideout") === false) {
      $("#main-nav-toggle").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```